# BiDirectional Key to <-> "CompositKey" lookup in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

Am writing a Go application on GAE 
And I have a type called `Connection{Token, ToAdress, FromAdress}`

I want to store it in the datastore so that I can look it up via
`GetConnectionByT(Token string)`
But also via
`GetConnectionByA(FromAdress,ToAdress string)`

What is the best way of doing this? Right now my Connect type have two different `.key()` functions and I insert duplicate entry's with different keys every time I add but this feels really really wrong :)

Is `datastore.NewQuery("Connection").Filter` the way to go? Seames that a key should be faster and cheaper? But if not how do I filter multiple fields?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a short code example?

Comment: It's all simply comes down to a question if you can set two keys on an datatsore entity, but i gues that is not possible? So I when with Chaining FIlters 4 now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [the documentation for datastore.Query.Filter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Filter) you'll note that multiple filters are ANDed together. So you can do this kind of thing:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Connection").
    Filter("FromAddress =", a1).
    Filter("ToAddress =", a2).
    Order("-FromAddress")
```

If you have a key for the entity in question then yes, using the key will probably be faster. However it's a bit difficult to tell from the description in your question.